# How to resolve AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'listLayers' in Python 3 for ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcpy, python, arcgis-pro

I have written several scripts for ArcGIS Pro and this error shows up occasionally and stumps me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 10, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'listLayers'
```

Simple code example:

```
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
m = aprx.listMaps("pdf_template")
for lyr in m.listLayers():
    print(lyr.name)
```

line 10 is `for lyr in m.listLayers():`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `aprx.listMaps()` methods returns a `list` object with all the maps for the ArcGIS Projects. If you pass a wildcard, in your case `"pdf_template"`, it will still return a list with all the maps that match the wildcard (even if it is only one). In order to use the `listLayers()` method, you need to get the map first by indexing the list. For example, to get the first (or only) map you can write the following:

```py
m = aprx.listMaps("pdf_template")[0]
```

Comment: Okay, I had tried it with index 0 first and the error i got was index out of range. Is that error beyond the scope of this question?

Comment: That means that the `listMaps()` method returned an empty list. Probably the wildcard you used does not match any of you map names. Make sure to use an useful wildcard (*i.e.* something that matches the name of the map) or simply call the method without using a wildcard to return all the maps and grab the first one: `m = aprx.listMaps()[0]`.